OpenMP Potential Data Race Not Happening
I am doing matrix multiplication using 1d array with Openmp. For the following code, I think data race may happen as I try to access the same location in different threads. However, it works fine and the answer is right.
The reason why I thing data race may happen:
When I printed out thread_id, i and j, I found different threads may iterate through the same i and j, leading to accessing same location in the matrix in different threads at the same time. Therefore, I think data race may occur there. P.S. I have already tried using matrix size with 1024 and the answer is still right.
#include <iostream>
#include "matmul.h"
#include <omp.h>

void mmul(const float* A, const float* B, float* C, const std::size_t n){
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(static)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                #pragma omp critical
                {
                    int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
                    std::cout << thread_id << " ";
                    std::cout << i << " " << j << '\n';
                }
                C[i*n + j] += A[i*n + k] * B[k*n + j];
            }
        }
    }
}

If I set n to 2 and use 3 threads to run, the output result is like the following:
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 0
0 0 1
1 1 0 //here
1 1 1
2 1 0 //here
2 1 1

Doesn't that mean both thread 1 and 2 are trying to access i=1, j=0, and that leads to data race?

Having a data race in C/C++ doesn't mean that you will see an impact to the expected result. A data race means that the behavior of your program is undefined. You still have the chance to see the expected result, but you might as well see complete garbage. Your program has a data race for writing to C. Do you compile with optimization flags?

This is not how you detect data races. Use ThreadSanitizer.

"Absence of Evidence is not Evidence of Absence" . Yes, there is a race condition and whether you can see it depends of the scheduling, the compiler, the CPU µ-architecture, input parameters, etc. Here, you use a static scheduling with collapse(2) which likely prevent the race condition to happen if the number of thread is small (and n can be divided by it). On many core CPUs with a relatively small matrix, you should see the issue, especially on ARM CPUs which has a different way to manage the coherence of their cache.

If you play with other scheduling (eg. schedule(dynamic)) or OMP_NUM_THREADS, you might see the problem too.

@Joachim Yes. I use the following g++ task1.cpp matmul.cpp -Wall -O3 -std=c++17 -o task1 -fopenmp. I think I should turn it off the observe the original behavior of my code, right?

@JérômeRichard Yes. When I tried with schedule(dynamic, 7) to set up the chunk size, data race happens.

Using ThreadSanitizer (as suggested above) with OpenMP applications can produce many false positive reports, if Archer is not loaded. Archer is only available with clang-based compilers on Linux/MacOs, but not with gcc or Windows. Testing with ThreadSanitizer shows, that there is no data race, if n is evenly divisible by the number of threads. So, if you start 8 threads with n=1000, the work distribution for collapse(2) will be similar to the distribution without collapse clause which is free of data race.

I would just get rid of the collapse clause. As long as you have far less threads than n, the outer loop gives enough parallelism, there wont be any race condition as there will be a unique mapping between i and the thread id and it might even help with locality/caching.
